# Solve equation $x^2 \cdot |x| = 2 \cdot \bar{x}$ in complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Well, to solve it I firstly tried to use exponential form. However, it didn't give me expected result. Also, I tried using trigonometric form but I am a bit inexperienced in it, so I couldn't observe anything interesting with it either.

I am new to complex numbers, so I would love to hear some advices on how to think of solution in such equations and maybe some insights on how to solve this one.

Comment: Instead of trig form, it's more algebraically illuminating to divide both sides by $|x|$ and use exponential polar form $re^{i\theta}$. Or you could multiply both sides by $x$ and simplify from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would we to substitute $x \in \mathbb{C}$ with $x = a + b i$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.
Put this in the equation:
$$
(a^2 + 2abi -b^2)(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}) = 2 (a - bi)
$$
Comparing reall and imaginary part leads to
$$
\begin{align}
a^2 \sqrt{a^2+b^2} - b^2 \sqrt{a^2+b^2}  &= 2 a \\
2 a b \sqrt{a^2+b^2} &= -2 b \\
\end{align}
$$

You can solve this and get to a couple of solutions:
$$
\begin{align}
a &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, & b &= -\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \quad \lor \\
a &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, & b &= \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \quad \lor \\
a &= 0, & b &= 0 \quad \lor \\
a &= \sqrt{2}, & b &= 0
\end{align}
$$

//EDIT: I forgot the "2" on the right side... fixed it

Answer (score 4):

Note that\begin{align}\require{cancel}x^2|x|=2\overline x&\implies\bigl|x^2|x|\bigr|=\left|2\overline x\right|\\&\iff|x|^3=2|x|.\end{align}Therefore, $|x|=0$ or $|x|=\sqrt2$. In the first case, we have $x=0$, which is indeed a solution of the equation. Otherwise, $x=\sqrt2e^{i\theta}$, for some $\theta\in\Bbb R$, and your equation becomes$$\cancel{2\sqrt2}e^{2i\theta}=\cancel{2\sqrt2}e^{-i\theta}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: The left-hand side should be $2\sqrt 2e^{2i\theta}$, I think.

Comment: @TonyK Sure! I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: In your first step you take the abs - which is not an equivalent conversion, therefore you loose some solutions.

Comment: Not at all! It's the other way around. The final equation may provide false solutions. So, you have to check each of them to see whether or not they are solutions of the initial equation.

Comment: With your last equation one gets the angles 0 and $\pi$, which results all in all in three solution: $x = 0, x = -\sqrt{2}, x = \sqrt{2}$.
Nevertheless then you have the wrong solution $-\sqrt{2}$ and you are missing $x = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-i \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ and $x = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$... or am I missing something here?

Comment: My last equation is $e^{2i\theta}=e^{-i\theta}$, which is equivalent to $e^{3i\theta}=1$. This provides $3$ solutions, corresponding to $\theta=0$, $\theta=\frac{2\pi}3$, and $\theta=\frac{4\pi}3$. These $3$ solutions are $\sqrt2$, $-\frac1{\sqrt2}+\sqrt{\frac32}i$, and $-\frac1{\sqrt2}-\sqrt{\frac32}i$. So, where exactly did I get a wrong solution?

Comment: Oh, I really just see now what you did in your first post... When you write "your equation becomes" you mean the initial equation - not the equation where you have taken the abs! That makes of course perfectly sense, otherwise this step would be wrong. I just didn't get why you take the abs value...
I see now what you did... but you could just have written everything in exponential Form in step 1 to get to this: $x^2 \rightarrow r^2 \rm{e}^{i 2 a}$, $|x| \rightarrow r$, $\bar{x} \rightarrow r^2 \rm{e}^{- i a}$.

Comment: @mathse Well, I wrote *your* equation, because I was talking about the equation written by the user who posted the question. Otherwise, it would have been *my* equation.

Answer (score 0):

The given equation $2 \bar{x} =x^2 |x|$ implies
$$2x=\bar{x}^2|x|=\left(\frac{x^2|x|}2\right)^2|x|=\frac14x^4|x|^3\implies x(x^3|x|^3-8)=0
$$
which leads to $x=0$ and $x|x|=2e^{i \frac{2\pi n}3}$. The second equation leads to $|x|=\sqrt2$, and in turn the corresponding solutions
$$x=\sqrt2 e^{i \frac{2\pi n}3}$$